# Working with js to change items/pictures as tabs are clicked

Tags: javascript

Im attempting to make a dollmaker, and Everyone uses "Drag and Drop". Unfortunately, this does not work for me as im trying to save the doll in a Database where it can be changed at any time.

Now i found an awesome dollmaker(Link here: http://minidollz.ninique.net/code/dollmaker_demo/index.html)

And it uses the drag and drop feature for the items(hair, shirts, etc) however beneath the doll building area itself, it has thumbnails to change the tone of the doll, and it works just how i want it. you click the thumbnail, and the doll changes color. I am certain this could be fine tuned and used for my own scripts.

Now, this is the active JS that makes the change on click work:

```
$("#swatchesArea a").click( function() {
    var changeSrc = $(this).attr("href");
    var type = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    switch (type) {
        case "skinSwitch":
            $("#skintone").attr("src", changeSrc);
            break;
        case "eyeSwitch":
            $("#eyes").attr("src", changeSrc);
            break;
    }



    return false;
});
```

Im wondering if it can be generalized to be used in any code? i mean, im positive it can. Its just i have way more experience with HTML and CSS, and i know very little javascript.

So in short, id like to generalize this code to be used in other websites/webpages, and do the same thing. Please reference http://minidollz.ninique.net/code/dollmaker_demo/index.html.

can someone help me?

Comment: can you setup a fiddle for this?

Comment: didnt even know something existed! Ill try it out^^